# When I tried to Print Hello World on Eclipse Console nothing is printing

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is the Script being used but nothing is printing on Eclipse Console and No Errors. Could someone Help me to get rid of this issue. This is happening since 2021.03 Eclipse Installed earlier I had Luna Version which was fine.

```java
package APIRestAssured;

public class LoginTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you doing to run the code, exactly?

Comment: This will be the most mysterious question I encounter on SO ! What exactly are you doing to fail this code!

Comment: @Vishal Maral I have the script in Eclipse Editor and then right Click>Run As>Java Application. So nothing is being printed on Console and No Errors also.

Comment: If using a fresh workspace (_File > Switch Workspace_) does not help, show a screenshot of your Eclipse IDE showing the Java editor, the file in the _Package Explorer_ and the _Console_ view.

Comment: Also check if eclipse is pointing to correct jdk path.